# How to mix in generated sprites mixins to loop-generated classes in LESS?

Tags: less, mixins

I'd like to generate multiple classes with mixed in sprites, using recursive, guarded mixins (and LESS compiler version 1.7).

The basic idea looks like this:

```
.sprite-img {
    background: url("sprite.png") no-repeat;
}
.icon_1 { width: 26px; height: 23px; background-position: -27px -27px; }
.icon_1_hover { width: 26px; height: 23px; background-position: -73px -51px; }
.icon_2 { width: 26px; height: 22px; background-position: -73px -28px; }
.icon_2_hover { width: 26px; height: 22px; background-position: 0 -48px; }

// setup some lists
@colors: #efa, #a77 ...;
@IDs: 1, 10,...;
.generate-colored-toggles(@n, @i: 1) when ( @i =< @n) {
    @c: extract(@colors, @i); // subtracts 1 from index for list access
    @j: extract(@IDs, @i);

    .container .toggle._@{j} .img-holder {
        border-color: @c;
        .sprite;

        /* LESS compiler error: */
        .icon_@{i}; // adding parentheses won't work either
        &:hover {
            .icon_@{i}_hover;
        }
    }

    .generate-colored-toggles(@n, (@i + 1)); // recurse
}
.generate-colored-toggles(length(@colors));
```

The resulting classes ( ._1 ... ._n ) are to be assigned, dynamically (in a loop, cf. JSF's ui-repeat), during page generation.

Now I'm facing numerous limitations:

- My sprites are generated using http://zerosprites.com/; thus, names of the sprite mixin classes *.icon_* are taken from the image file names, and should therefore not be modified.
- The *.toggle*'s structure is determined by my widget library and should be left unchanged. This prevents me from assigning the specific sprite image class to the *.img-holder* directly in the markup.

Can you think of a workaround (preferably, using LESS only)?

Comment: Interpolation of an invoked mixin name is not supported (and is not planned to be supported). I would suggest a dumb and thus unbeatable brute-force method: "big copy-pasted mixin call thunk table" like [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/9950683) or [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/9950738). (In a perfect world I'd suggest you to consider to switch to some smarter/customizable sprite generation tool/library).

Comment: I Like your second solution, using :extend, since the *background* definitions aren't duplicated during compilation.

Comment: I would accept this as an answer, since the "interpolatable" table stays valid when I regenerate the sprite, making it sufficiently reusable and maintainable for my use-case.